# How Device receives Direct Methods in the IoT Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

As per the documentation of the Direct Method in the IoT Hub, it is stated that the user invokes a direct method through a service-facing URI **"{iot hub}/twins/{device id}/methods/"** and the device receives it on the MQTT topic **"$iothub/methods/POST/{method name}/"**

I have some confusion regarding how this mapping works.

Is there any internal mapping in the IoT hub that redirects the request to the specific device?

How do other devices identify that the method is not meant for them because the topic on which the device is listening does not seem to be device specific and we need only a particular device to receive that method invocation?

Comment: Azure IoT Hub is not generic MQTT Broker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure IoT Hub is a bidirectional integration gateway between a device and cloud (IoT Stack). Its primary goal is a fast ingestion of the device telemetry data to the cloud stream pipeline via a default (built-in) or custom endpoints.

Basically, the Azure IoT Hub has two kind of endpoints such as device-facing endpoints and service-facing endpoints. 
More details about these endpoints is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-endpoints).

Internally, the Azure IoT Hub is not a bus oriented, it's not a generic MQTT Broker, it's not a generic communication broker, it is an integration gateway with a point-to-point star topology communications such as Device-To-Cloud (D2C) and Cloud-To-Device (C2D) messaging. There is no direct Device-To-Device messaging.

The C2D messaging has some limitations, see [IoT Hub quotas and throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling).
The C2D messaging can be in async or sync manner using a device twin features.

Basically, the C2D messaging is based on the point-to-point star communication, in other words you can not send a multicast broadcasting message to the devices. In this case, the recommend way is to create a job for sending a message to devices one by one.

Invoking a Direct Method on the device via the Azure IoT Hub is only via the service-facing endpoint using a Http protocol. On the other end such as a device-facing endpoint, it can be consumed only by device with a connection oriented protocol such as MQTT or AMQP.

The device-facing endpoint supports a MQTT v3.1.1 communication protocol, see more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly).

To evaluate behavior of the MQTT device with Azure IoT Hub can be done with 3rd party tools such as MQTTBox Client, https://iotdevtool.com, [Azure IoT Hub Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester), etc.

The following screen snippets show invoking a Direct Method on the MQTT Device. Note the Azure IoT Hub Tester using a direct MQTT protocol with an Azure IoT Hub.

Step 1: Invoking a Direct Method on the service-facing endpoint (Http). Note, that the url address has a target device id (in this test Device10).
[image: step1]

Step 2: The device (Device10) received a direct method
[image: step2]

Step 3: The device (Device10) sent the response back to the invoker
[image: step3]

Step 4: The invoker received a response from the Device10 within the timeout limit
[image: step4]

Answer (score 0):

When a device authenticates with IoT Hub, it includes its device id. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly

IoT Hub can then ensure devices receive the correct direct method invocations.

Comment: We are kind of looking for the internal process that takes place when a direct method is invoked. How IoT Hub processes it to the targeted device through a common topic that all the devices are listening.

Answer (score 0):

Each Direct Method target a single device even if multi direct methods have the same name only the targeted device can receive the method.

So feel free to test and use it.

Comment: We are looking to use MQTT topics directly in our code, thus we need to know how the devices receive their specific requests because all the devices are listening on a common topic rather than device specific topics.

Comment: @RahulBansal Have you tested and what's the problem you encountered?

Comment: We haven't tested this yet. We are evaluating this theoretically as whether it will suit our problem statement or not. We are trying to understand how it actually works, the internal mapping of the IoT Hub and the devices for direct method.